# ZUUIRevealController with UITabBarController instead of UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, tabbar

I'm trying to implement the ZUUIRevealController into a project of mine, this app uses a UITabBarController with 3 tabs.

I went through the screencast and sample code multiple times, but I can't figure out why

```
[self.navigationController.parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(revealToggle)]
```

only responds with false.

In my appdelegate I just create a simple UITabBarController and add is as a rootViewController:

```
UITableViewController *activityViewController = [[[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *agendaViewController = [[[AgendaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AgendaViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *settingsViewController = [[[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

UINavigationController *activityNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:activityViewController] autorelease];
UINavigationController *agendaNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:agendaViewController] autorelease];
UINavigationController *settingsNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsViewController] autorelease];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:activityNavController, agendaNavController, settingsNavController, nil];

SortViewController *sortViewController = [[SortViewController alloc] init];    
ZUUIRevealController *revealController = [[ZUUIRevealController alloc] initWithFrontViewController:self.tabBarController rearViewController:sortViewController];
[sortViewController release];

//self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
self.window.rootViewController = revealController;

[revealController release];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But when I do the check in my ActivityViewController, I only get false

```
if([self.tabBarController.parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(revealToggle)]) 
{
    NSLog(@"YAY");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"WRONG");
}
```

It seems so simple in the screencast, but it looks like I'm missing something.

ZUUIRevealController: https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put **`:`** in the if statement while you checking  for ***`respondsToSelector:`*** like

```
if([self.tabBarController.parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(revealToggle:)])
```